# Cовместимость Angular с IE 7

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

Вчера задался этим вопросом и до сих пор не получается, хотя в доках anglare всё черным по белому написано и много ответов на stackoverflow.. Сделал самый просто пример и буду рад, если Вы подскажете на его примере ( лучше прям его изменить ), чтобы он заработал.
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" id="ng-app" ng-app='app'>
<head>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tests</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">{{ message }}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.message = "Hello!";
})
```

[image]

Comment: забудьте о ие7

Comment: а вариант с angular.bootstrap(document);  пробовали ?

Comment: а это майкрософт. Они по умолчанию любят включить режим эмуляции. У них есть специальный сервис, который отслеживает, какой режим выбирают люди для разных страниц и соответственно переключают в браузере.

Но я думаю, они сами хотят искоренить свой браузер, поэтому и выставляют.

Comment: ткните на синенькую надпись и измените в ней.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Читайте доки [глубже](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie):

> Note: AngularJS 1.3 is dropping support for IE8. Read more about it on our blog. AngularJS 1.2 will continue to support IE8, but the core team does not plan to spend time addressing issues specific to IE8 or earlier.

AngularJS 1.3 уже не поддерживает IE8. AngularJS 1.2 будет поддерживать IE8, но разработчики не планируют тратить время на баги, которые специфичны для IE.

Там же, описано, как заставить работать под 7 IE, но с определенными ограничениями. Если у Вас AngularJS 1.3 - то работать не будет, только на AngularJS 1.2.

Comment: Работать будет что угодно, если постараться.